# Is this a Möbius transformation? Line $\mapsto$ hyperbola

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I was trying to make a Möbius transformation $M:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ with $2$ fixed points. What I did was:

Make a degree 2 formula $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=cz^2+dz-az-b=0 $ so $c\ne 0$ and

choose $a,b,c,d$ arbitrarily.

So I want $(a,b,c,d)=(0,2,3,0)$ giving me $M(z)=\frac{2}{3z}$

I can solve for the fixed points like this:

$3z^2 -2 =0\implies z=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ are two fixed points.

I graph it and I get the following [image]

It is not a circle or a straight line? But I thought Möbius transforms took straight lines to circles or more straight lines?

Is $ M(z)=z= \frac{2}{3z}$ still a Möbius transform, even though it turns a line 
into a hyperbola?

Tip: For typing ö,(German Umlaut) hold Alt and type 148.

Comment: why the downvote? i used the mathjax tutorial?

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted. I think this is a reasonable question. Some people are a bit happy with the downvoting. :/

Comment: @CameronWilliams I think it's my grammer, but as long as someone answers my question I am happy

Comment: im a member now, so maybe people will give me and answer?

Comment: is this question bad?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Möbius transformations map the set of lines and circles to the set of lines and circles.

If you restrict your $M$ to the real axis, what you see in the picture is the *graph* of the function, not the image.

Since $M$ is real valued on the real axis, the image is actually the projection of the graph on the $y$-axis. I.e. the images is the real axis itself ($M(\infty) = 0$ to fill in the gap). No contradiction here.

Comment: So if it was plotted correctly it would look like a circle? I don't fully understand, but I think you are saying that the graph $\ne$ image and that the image is a line or a circle and that thus this is a mobius transformation

Comment: No. Your $M$ maps the real axis to itself.